# what is wrong in JSON data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, ajax, ejs

```
"gsdata" :[{"id":7,"SCRIP":"ASIANPAINT","LTP":3341,"OHL":"BUY","ORB15":"BREAKOUT","ORB30":"NT","PRB":"NA","CAMARILLA":"Buy","ALERT":3327.4,"PROFIT":null,"createdAt":"2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"},{"id":10,"SCRIP":"BAJAJ-AUTO","LTP":3699.4,"OHL":"NA","ORB15":"BREAKDOWN","ORB30":"BREAKDOWN","PRB":"BREAKDOWN","CAMARILLA":"Buy","ALERT":3699.4,"PROFIT":null,"createdAt":"2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"},{"id":15,"SCRIP":"BERGEPAINT","LTP":833.65,"OHL":"NA","ORB15":"NA","ORB30":"NT","PRB":"NA","CAMARILLA":"Buy","ALERT":833.65,"PROFIT":null,"createdAt":"2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"},{"id":18,"SCRIP":"BIOCON","LTP":352.3,"OHL":"NA","ORB15":"BREAKDOWN","ORB30":"BREAKDOWN","PRB":"BREAKDOWN","CAMARILLA":"Short","ALERT":352.3,"PROFIT":null,"createdAt":"2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"},{"id":23,"SCRIP":"CDSL","LTP":1321.45,"OHL":"NA","ORB15":"NA","ORB30":"NT","PRB":"BREAKUP","CAMARILLA":"Buy","ALERT":null,"PROFIT":null,"createdAt":"2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z","updatedAt":"2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"}]
```

This is a JSON array data.I am using populate this data using ajax. but getting below warning message

```
DataTables warning: table id=scrip-data - Invalid JSON response
```

can somebody point me where I am doing wrong.Below is my ajax snippet to load dataTable.

```
var data1 = JSON.parse('<%- gsdata %>') ; //ejs template to read value of data send from controller    
var table = $('#scrip-data').DataTable( {
    "searching": false,
    paging: false,
    info: false,
    "processing": true,
    //"serverSide": true,
        ajax: {
            url: "dashboard",
            //type: "GET",
            dataSrc: "",
        },
        data: data1,
        //dataType: 'json',
        columns: [
            {data: "SCRIP"},
            {data: "LTP"},
            {data: "CAMARILLA"},
            {data: "ALERT"},
            {data: "PROFIT"},
            {data: "updatedAt"},
        ],
        //columnDefs: [{ }],
    } );

    setInterval( function () {
            table.ajax.reload();
        }, 20000 );
```

Comment: It misses surrounding curly braces

Comment: The quoted JSON is indeed invalid. It needs `{` at the beginning and `}` at the end. If you add them, it's valid. Alternatively, remove the `"gsdata" :` at the beginning to *just* have an array. (With the `{}` it's an object with a `gsdata` property.)

Answer (score 0):

Just add the curly brackets around the json string.

```
{
    "gsdata": [{
        "id": 7,
        "SCRIP": "ASIANPAINT",
        "LTP": 3341,
        "OHL": "BUY",
        "ORB15": "BREAKOUT",
        "ORB30": "NT",
        "PRB": "NA",
        "CAMARILLA": "Buy",
        "ALERT": 3327.4,
        "PROFIT": null,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"
    }, {
        "id": 10,
        "SCRIP": "BAJAJ-AUTO",
        "LTP": 3699.4,
        "OHL": "NA",
        "ORB15": "BREAKDOWN",
        "ORB30": "BREAKDOWN",
        "PRB": "BREAKDOWN",
        "CAMARILLA": "Buy",
        "ALERT": 3699.4,
        "PROFIT": null,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"
    }, {
        "id": 15,
        "SCRIP": "BERGEPAINT",
        "LTP": 833.65,
        "OHL": "NA",
        "ORB15": "NA",
        "ORB30": "NT",
        "PRB": "NA",
        "CAMARILLA": "Buy",
        "ALERT": 833.65,
        "PROFIT": null,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"
    }, {
        "id": 18,
        "SCRIP": "BIOCON",
        "LTP": 352.3,
        "OHL": "NA",
        "ORB15": "BREAKDOWN",
        "ORB30": "BREAKDOWN",
        "PRB": "BREAKDOWN",
        "CAMARILLA": "Short",
        "ALERT": 352.3,
        "PROFIT": null,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"
    }, {
        "id": 23,
        "SCRIP": "CDSL",
        "LTP": 1321.45,
        "OHL": "NA",
        "ORB15": "NA",
        "ORB30": "NT",
        "PRB": "BREAKUP",
        "CAMARILLA": "Buy",
        "ALERT": null,
        "PROFIT": null,
        "createdAt": "2021-09-09T15:31:02.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-09-10T16:34:01.000Z"
    }]
}
```